# How can I programmatically close all other applications from my iPhone application?

Tags: iphone

Is it possible to programmatically close all running applications on the iPhone except my own from within my own application?  If so, how?

Comment: Your users aren't going to be very happy if you were able to do this.

Comment: there are many reasons for doing that, for example I would like to kill procesess that are running in background spying my Iphone, do you know, there are some applications that register all Iphone activity so it could be good to kill that process that is runinng hidden.

Answer (score 2):

No. All apps run in a sandbox so that you can't communicate between them. And even if you technically could it would be considered bad practice.

Why do you need to close other apps? I can't think of any valid use case where that would be necessary.

Comment: maybe in order to have a powerful remote that can shut others' iphone on demand, isn't it obvious? : D

Comment: Thanks Stephen for the answer.

Comment: But Is it possible to close all applications by clicking on home button. I mean programmatically, is it possible ?

Comment: You can exit your app when someone presses the home button. But you can't affect any other running app.

Comment: The question does not ask for advice on best practises, but for a technical answer. Perhaps the OP has a very good reason to want to do this, which you simply do not know.

Comment: @StephanBijzitter The first two sentences explain the technical answer. Having a valid use case doesn't change that.

Answer (score 1):

An app doesn't have access to the home button on a stock device.  The only other access to any other apps in the background is if they have registered a URL handler.

Answer (score -1):

It's not possible and there's also no need to.

There are very conservative limits on how much processing a background app can use and if the result of low memory warnings is that there still isn't enough memory, the OS will automatically start killing things. Don't try to be clever - it's just as willing to kill you and indeed will kill you first if nothing else is running.

Comment: The question does not ask for advice on best practises, but for a technical answer. Perhaps the OP has a very good reason to want to do this, which you simply do not know.

Comment: @StephanBijzitter "It's not possible" is a technical answer. Mine isn't about best practices, it's about why Apple has made the policy decision that what he wants to do is not possible. So it's to explain why "it's not possible" is the correct, technical answer.