# I need to kill user applications running on iPad while my applications remains running

Tags: iphone, ios, process, kill

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I programmatically close all other applications from my iPhone application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4003647/how-can-i-programmatically-close-all-other-applications-from-my-iphone-applicatio)

I am developing a test application to discover the capabilities of IOS system, so I would like to know if there is some way where  I can get the list of all processes running on My DEVICE said it: Iphone, Ipad or Ipod. Then I would like to use the PID List or Process Id list to iterate over it and Kill them all, one by one but only certain processes specially those which were started by the user and aren't critical process of the system.
I have found some example from XCODE documentation about how to kill processes running on MAC OS but nothing about IOS, I dont know the starting point to begin my searching, or what  is the IOS framework I need to seek.

Comment: Apple really doesn't want apps killing other apps, for good reason.

Comment: Wow, keylogging as well as killing other apps, must be some lovely app you're dreaming up there. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5342687/hooking-iphone-system

Comment: there are many reasons for doing that, for example I would like to kill procesess that are running in background spying my Iphone, do you know there are some applications that register all Iphone activity so it could be good to kill that process that is runinng hidden.

Answer (score 5):

You can't, iOS doesn't allow you to access other applications at all.

Comment: unless you jailbreak...but that's _another_ whole can of worms

Comment: sssssh Luke, don't tell the script kiddy...

Comment: I found something interesting, it exists a framework of low level where you can get access to a low level system, until now I am reviewing all the documentation so I hope to find the key of the matter very soon!

Comment: I have an app, "SystemLite" on my ipad2. It shows all of the running processes.